# Rename a hidden file on OS X

Tags: macos

I have a file called ".hgignore copy" and I want to rename it to ".hgignore".  With a regular file, if I click on the name in the finder, I can change it.  But with a hidden file, it won't let me do that.  How can I change the name?

Comment: It won't show the file, it won't let you click on the file, or it won't let you rename it? Which?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the worst case you could always open a terminal and rename it there.

```
mv ".hgignore copy" .hgignore
```

Comment: typed faster, i'll delete mine

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way, I've found, is to CTRL(right)-click on the file, choose Get Info, change the name in the Name and Extension box, and hit Return (or just close the Get Info window).

Comment: The OP asked about when files are invisible. If they are invisible (and not made visible like in Daniel Beck's answer) you can not do this. This answer doesn't help at all.

Comment: @Rich Homolka He asked about hidden files - you can change OSX to display hidden files (dotfiles) in finder.  This answer works well if you have made your hidden files visible.

Answer (score 3):

You can rename the file in Terminal by entering

```
mv .hgignore\ copy .hgignore
```

---

You can also enable displaying of hidden files in Finder by entering

```
 defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
```

in Terminal and restarting Finder by entering

```
 killall Finder
```

afterwards

---

A more user-friendly alternative to the second part of this answer is the use of [Secrets](http://secrets.blacktree.com/), a "preference pane" extension for `System Preferences`, that lets you set this "hidden files" option for Finder in a more userfriendly way.

Comment: Blacktree link is no longer valid. It would be great if there was a com entry for renaming hidden files.